# How to verify field of type byte array (byte[]) through pact jvm?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, pact

I am currently writing contract tests for rest services using Pact jvm. One of the field in the response body in both consumer and provider is of type byte[] (byte array). I don't see any matcher for such field. How can we verify such fields?

```
class MediaResponse{
private long mediaId;
private String mediaName;
private byte[] media;
private String mediaLink;
private boolean isStreamable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not have a type for byte arrays, so there is no way we can know how it is encoded. My guess is that it would be encoded as something like `base64` into a `string` type. We don't have matchers for such types, but you could consider raising a feature request.

If you must check the type, my suggestion would be to use a provider state and ensure a small `byte[]` is sent as it will need to be a byte by byte comparison.